# Running test directly on Selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a very old Rails 2 app (yeah, that old) and I'm about to upgrade it to Rails 6.
The app comes with a suite of tests written in RSelenese and running with the [selenium-on-rails plugin](https://github.com/paytonrules/selenium-on-rails). For reference, here a sample test:

```
setup :fixtures => "masters/all"

#
include_partial 'login', :username => "tom.doh", :password => "Secret123", :language => "en"

#
open "/masters/new"
type "id=master_name", "Test Master"
click "link=subcategory"
click "id=master_originator_id_1"
click_and_wait "id=master_submit"
#
verify_text_present "name: Test Master"
```

For the time being, I'd like to be able while transitioning to Rails 6, to still running those tests (I plan to replace them with RSpec System tests once the app runs on Rails 6).

Is there a way to use the [selenium-webdriver](https://rubygems.org/gems/selenium-webdriver) gem to run (R)Selenese tests?

Comment: I don't really think they are the least bit compatible. When upgrading from a rails version that old you're going to have to do extensive re-writes to the point where you're questioning why you didn't just start fresh and cherry pick the reusable parts like views.

Comment: Also selenium-webdriver is used together with capybara which provides the actual DSL that you use in minitest / rspec to actually manipulate the browser. I have never really heard of (R)Selenese but from a quick looks like it appears to be a bastard stepchild of the driver and something resembling capybara. I doubt you can get it to run in any modern version of Rails. You best bet is probably just to rewrite the tests with capybara.